# Xcode 11 - I can connect actions but not outlets?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode11

Let me preface by saying that I haven't worked on any Xcode projects on this machine before. I normally work on a computer at my school, but I'm using another as I am away right now.

I was following along with a tutorial video from a Swift course that I'm taking, but I quickly realized that Xcode isn't giving me the option to connect any outlets. If I attempt to connect a UITextField, it only gives me the option to connect an action. If I attempt to connect a UILabel, it won't give me any options at all. I am used to being given the option to connect Outlets, Outlet Connections, and Actions on a UITextField (and UIButton) and being given the sole option of Outlet on a UILabel.

I've tried to fix the issue by setting the 'class' of the ViewController, but I didn't find any options for that.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!!

[attempting to connect UITextField Outlet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWDc5.png)

[attempting to connect UILabel Outlet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvXzy.png)

[UITextField not giving any option other than Action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzX1c.png)

Github repository - https://github.com/plates-the-one/noOutlet

Comment: Can you link your project? I'll take a look.

Comment: Sure! I put it on Github, if that works. Sorry if I do things a little unconventionally; I'm a student and I don't have much experience with larger scale programs, etc.

Comment: so am I, no problem!

Comment: Seems fine to me... https://imgur.com/a/cIbwiGd

Comment: I downloaded your github repository (extremely annoying zip within a zip) and there are no instance properties and no text fields in the storyboard so what are we even talking about? — Also, are you sure you're editing the right storyboard? There was something in your LaunchStoryboard, but there's no such thing as an outlet in a launch storyboard because it has no associated code. You should be working in the `main` storyboard. But it's empty, as I said, so I don't see what the question is about.

Comment: There's no content because normally the first thing I do is create my outlets. My issue is that I cannot create outlets on my program, but I suppose that must be an issue unique to my computer. (also sorry, I didn't realize Github automatically compressed files, I've never used it before today)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are attempting to do all this in the wrong storyboard. Work in *Main.storyboard*, not in *LaunchScreen.storyboard*.

Also it is crucial that you select the Identity inspector in the storyboard and change the Class from UIViewController to ViewController.

Answer (score 1):

I think when you are drawing a outlet, must be some `issue with the type`.

When you see the below `outlet connection` popup, change the type of the view from Any to the respective `UIView` type(`UITextField` and `UILabel` in your case)

Don't forget to change the `connection` from `Action` to `outlet` after you have changed the `type`

This must solve your issue. Comment if it solves your problem

[image: Change Type from Any to UITextField/UILabel]

Comment: Hello! Unfortunately that didn't work. I changed the type and still wasn't given the option to change the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Xcode is picky when a custom class is specified in the storyboard. A workaround is to write the `@IBOutlet` manually and the connect it to the UI element in the storyboard